OpenFeign Client - Multiple Basic Authentication token gets applied to the same request
Let's say I have 2 feign clients as below -
@FeignClient(name = "app1", url = "${app1.uri}", configuration = AppOneFeignClientConfiguration.class)
public interface AppOneClient {
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/name", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    String getName();
}

@FeignClient(name = "app2", url = "${app2.uri}", configuration = AppTwoFeignClientConfiguration.class)
public interface AppTwoClient {
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/address", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    String getAddress();
}

and below are the Configuration classes for these two clients -
public class AppOneFeignClientConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "appOneBasicAuth")
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor appOneBasicAuthRequestInterceptor(
            @Value("${app1_user_name}") String username,
            @Value("${app1_password}") String password
    ) {
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor(username, password);
    }

    @Bean(name = "appOneClientLogger")
    Logger.Level appOneFeignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.BASIC;
    }
}

public class AppTwoFeignClientConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "appTwoBasicAuth")
    public BasicAuthRequestInterceptor appTwoBasicAuthRequestInterceptor(
            @Value("${app2_user_name}") String username,
            @Value("${app2_password}") String password
    ) {
        return new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor(username, password);
    }

    @Bean(name = "appTwoClientLogger")
    Logger.Level appTwoFeignLoggerLevel() {
        return Logger.Level.BASIC;
    }
}

So with these settings in place, if I invoke AppOneClient.getName(), I expected that the authentication prescribed in the AppOneFeignClientConfiguration class would be applied to the request. But what I find out instead is that it applied both the basic auths (described in the 2 configuration classes above) to the same request, and I see the following 2 basic auth authorization headers being included in the same call -
Authorization: Basic ZnVzaW9uLWNybS1vYWwtc2FsZXNfd3dAb3JhY2xlLmNvbTpjcm1PQUw0U2FsZXM=
Authorization: Basic ZnVzaW9uLWNybS1vYWwtc2FsZXNfd3dAb3JhY2xlLmNvbTpjcm1PQUw0U2FsZXM=
This causes the requests to fail with 400 bad request.
So wanted to check how to modify the setup above so that the basic auth configuration pertaining to a particular client only gets applied to that client, and not all the auth configurations get applied to the same request, as it is happening with the setup above. Thanks in advance for the guidance

Hard to say without seeing the full project. Snippets of configuration won't allow, in this case, to deduce anything.

Feel free to open an issue with a link to a sample project in https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign

You can't use the bean way to inject the same interceptor, this will be applied to all the feign, you should be the choice to implement the RequestInterceptor interface to operate. Otherwise your authentication won't pass and an exception will be thrown, and there will be a different Authorization in the request header.
Here's the configuration after the fix
import feign.RequestInterceptor;
import feign.RequestTemplate;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AppTwoFeignClientConfiguration implements RequestInterceptor {


    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public AppTwoFeignClientConfiguration(@Value("${app2_user_name}") String username,
                                          @Value("${app2_password}") String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
        requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes()));
    }
}

public class AppOneFeignClientConfiguration implements RequestInterceptor {


    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public AppOneFeignClientConfiguration(@Value("${app1_user_name}") String username,
                                        @Value("${app1_password}") String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public void apply(RequestTemplate requestTemplate) {
        requestTemplate.header("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes()));
    }
}


The usage is unchanged, still using the configuration = AppOneFeignClientConfiguration.class
